# Process XSL file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt, joomla, syndication-feed

My question is

Can someone point me into the right direction of what i need to search for in order to process just an XSL file with Joomla/PHP?

I have done quite a bit of searching on Google myself and all the results relate to having an XML file and a XSL file and proceeding from there.

The above is not the case for me. The coded XSL file pulls in the XML data into the XSL file from a syndication feed. I need to be able to process this file to display the results?

Does that make sense or have i got the wrong end of the stick?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XSL is a language for expressing style sheets. An XSL style sheet is, like with CSS, a file that describes how to display an XML document of a given type. XSL shares the functionality and is compatible with CSS2 (although it uses a different syntax).